# Seeking open access 10-30 m spatial resolution imagery?

Tags: data, satellite

The data from Landsat-8 and Sentinel-2A&B satellite missions is available at no cost.

I am curious to know if there are other sources of freely available multi-spectral moderate resolution satellite imagery?

I am obliged for pertinent information about currently operational satellite missions.

The moderate resolution satellite imagery within spatial resolution of 10-30 meters, with regional to global coverage. I think imagery from Sentinel-2 and Landsat-8 falls in the category of moderate resolution.

Comment: Modis? But it is at 250m resolution.

Comment: @Hornbydd I believe MODIS imagery nowadays falls in the category of coarse resolution.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am seeking geospatial open-source data. For the reason I am expecting answers from this forum that is more relevant to get pertinent information.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this USGS link:

https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

I am pretty sure this is all free data (don't quote me on this) but you can toggle a few options to check.

Answer (score 0):

Moderate Resolution Imaging Spectroradiometer (MODIS)
https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/
But you can also just check here for what you need:
https://webapps.itc.utwente.nl/sensor/default.aspx?view=allsensors